# How to swap plans and create invoice WITHOUT immediate payment using Laravel Cashier

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel-5, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

Laravel Cashier makes it pretty simple to swap plans:

```
$user->subscription('premium')
     ->swapAndInvoice();
```

This feature is also great because it invoices the user right away, HOWEVER, it also forces the user to pay right away rather than waiting an hour like it normally would. This seems to get in the way of my `invoice.created` webhook because once `swapAndInvoice` happens, I don't seem to be able to make further changes to the invoice.

If I just use `->swap()`, it doesn't appear to create an invoice at all, but rather it just creates line items waiting to be added to the next invoice. Thoughts are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Since posting this question, I have actually submitted a pull request to the Laravel Cashier repository to add a method within the `StripeGateway.php` file that can perform such functionality.

```
/**
 * Invoice the billable entity outside of regular billing cycle without charging the user immediately.
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function invoiceWithoutImmediateCharge()
{
    try
    {
        $customer = $this->getStripeCustomer();

        // Removed this because it immediately charges the user which doesn't allow the invoice to be modified by webhooks
        //Stripe_Invoice::create(['customer' => $customer->id], $this->getStripeKey())->pay();
        Stripe_Invoice::create(['customer' => $customer->id], $this->getStripeKey());

        return true;
    }
    catch (\Stripe_InvalidRequestError $e)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```